# Python "__setattr__" and "__getattribute__" confusion

Tags: python, python-internals

What is wrong with this code?

```
class Spam(object):

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    # using this to mark field "c" as deprecated. As per my understanding this gets called only for fields that do not exist.
    def __getattr__(self, c):
        print("Deprecated")

    # using this to manipulate the value before storing
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self.__dict__[name] = value + 1

    # interceptor to allows me to define rules for whenever an attribute's value is accessed
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        return self.__dict__[name] 

spam = Spam(10, 20)

print(spam.a)
print(spam.b)
print(spam.c)
```

But the above code doesn't print anything. Whats wrong here, can anyone help me understand this? I read about these methods in https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/#access

Comment: Hint: how is the attribute access `self.__dict__` resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the above code doesn't print anything

Wrong. It crashes with infinite recursion.

In `__getattribute__`, when you want to log/intercept the call, at some point you still want to get the original method to get the attribute. and `self.__dict__[name]` calls `__getattribute__` so it's not the proper way of doing it.

What you're trying calls this method again and you get infinite recursion. Call the parent/base method instead:

```
# interceptor to allows me to define rules for whenever an attribute's value is accessed
def __getattribute__(self, name):
    return object.__getattribute__(self,name)  # or super(Spam,self).__getattribute__(name)
```

that prints:

```
11
21
Deprecated
None
```

`None` is returned by `__getattr__` (because it just prints to the console and implicitly returns `None`). Maybe an exception would be a better idea.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. These magic methods call chain is bit confusing and counter-intuitive.

Comment: This is designed to be transparent, but you want to use some advanced features, and it's not easy to work with, yes. Remember that `object` is the mother of all classes, so you can rely on its methods, always.